# How to animate graphics on webpage?

Tags: javascript, animation, graphics

Ok, this might be a dumb question, but I'm completely new to this. I have no experience in graphic design, but it's something that I want to learn.

My end goal is to create a web-page with animated graphics, like this: http://kontramax.com/wp-content/uploads/envato/demo/coming_soon_machine/dark/

Or better yet, something more complicated like this: www.kennedyandoswald.com

How was the latter created?!

The problem is, I have no idea where to even start when it comes to animating graphics. I assume the first step is to create an animated graphic on a program like After Effects (or some other program I'm unaware of). Then, what? How do you code that onto a webpage? I'm learning JS/HTML/CSS right now.

Again, I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but we all have to start somewhere, and I hope you can help me out :)

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Making a website is different from making animated graphics, like gifs. If you are interested in the latter, you can do it via svg animations, programmatically, but it's not worth the effort. You should look into Adobe Illustrator tutorials, I think.

Answer (score -1):

There are few animation libraries you can integrate + you need to have command on CSS3 Keyframes so you can create and customize your animations.

Here are the few links of the libraries might be helpful to you.

```
 https://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/
 https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/
 https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp
```